# How do I change a Routing and Remote Access NAT rule session timeout

Tags: rras

I have to increase the HTTPS timeout in the routing and remote access nat rule so it works a little better with our ActiveSync direct push. I can't seem to find a netsh command nor a registry key. How do I change that timeout value?

EDIT: Windows Server 2003 SP2 Standard

Comment: What Windows Server is this running on and is it an SBS or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for:

```
netsh routing ip nat set global tcptimeoutmins=x
```

This sets the timeout on TCP NAT translations in minutes. See: 
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754535(WS.10).aspx

Comment: Perfect! That's what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to [set the idle timeout](http://www.howtonetworking.com/VPN/rrasrestrict1.htm) in the Routing and Remote Access Server administrative tool. Though in practice, you should have another firewall publishing and it's this firewall that needs to have the session timeout tweaked?

Comment: I am using the RRAS basic nat/firewall on this server. There is another firewall in front of it, but that one is configured correctly, it's this one that needs the timeout increased.

That link was for dial-in (i.e. VPN) connections, is that going to also affect the timeout for the SSL nat rule?